# Permissions Request dialog persist on application restart when permission is revoked

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, application-restart, runtime-permissions

My application is targeted to Android Marshmallow (API level 23) and implemented Run-time Permissions by following the developer guide in the below link.
[https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html.](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

This requesting Permission model is working fine.

When there is a permission request popup on the screen, If user **revoke** the permissions which are already granted by accessing **Settings -> Apps -> My Application name -> permission** and switch to my application, Application is getting restarted. 
But that permission Request dialog which is already opened still persist.

So, Please suggest some solution to close that **permission request dialog** which is already there in the screen, when it is getting restarted.

Comment: i had some problems like that too, are you inside a fragment or activity? are you using support? v4 or v7?

Comment: That dialog is from the system, not you. I am not aware of any way you can control it once launched.

Comment: i am also facing the same issue.did you got the solution??

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468